# Storing Visual Basic classes in separate files?

Tags: vb.net, class

In Java you can store a class in a separate file and instantiate it from a method in another file as long as the class file is in the same directory but this doesn't seem to work in Visual Basic.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You must be. Post your code and explain what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing files in the same directory doesn't mean much in VB.NET (or C#, for that matter).

If both classes are in the same [*namespace*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx) and the class you want to access/instantiate has [`Friend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx) or *wider* accessibility you should be able to instantiate it - nothing more should be required (assuming no private default constructor and such shenanigans).

Comment: Although I'd stab my fellow programmer who -- without a *real good* cause -- didn't keep the filesystem structure/namespace structure aligned...

Comment: @pst - I am with you there. Can't imagine this is the problem. OP is probably expecting default "package" accessibility as is in Java.